# Converting a 4 byte block to the corresponding int in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, byte

I am passing a sequence of bytes from my arduino which are the sensor readings and i need the integer values of these bytes. My byte blocks size is sizeof(int) * 18(because i have 18 sensors) where sizeof(int) is 4.

Can somebody please tell me how I can find the int value of 4 bytes in python? I need to do this for each sensor reading.

Comment: Do you want each byte converted to int seperately, or append the bytes and convert to 1 int? Can you add some sample input and expected output

Comment: sample data . can u add it:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
>>> import struct
>>> # assume the `sensor_values` is come from sensors.
>>> sensor_values = struct.pack('!18i', *range(100, 1900, 100))
>>> print struct.unpack('!18i', sensor_values)
(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000,
 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800)
```

`!` indicates the data is packed with network(big-endian). Use `<` if the data is packed with little-endian.